# No heapster filesystem metrics from REST API

Tags: kubernetes, heapster

I process a kubernetes proxy on my local machine through kubectl proxy. 
And I deployed heapster onto my kubernetes environment as well as influxdb and grafana.
I can see the metrics of filesystem usage retrieved by grafana.
[image]

However, I cannot get the filesystem usage through heapster REST API through:
[image]

Please help me to check if there is any misconfigured or url wrong or other issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some pods there is no such type of metrics as `filesystem/usage`:

Here is an example of available metrics list for etcd-minikube pod:

http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy/api/v1/model/namespaces/kube-system/pods/etcd-minikube/metrics/

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy/api/v1/model/namespaces/kube-system/pods/etcd-minikube/metrics/ 

[ 
  "network/rx_errors_rate", 
  "cpu/usage_rate", 
  "network/rx_errors", 
  "memory/request", 
  "memory/page_faults_rate", 
  "network/rx_rate", 
  "network/tx_errors_rate", 
  "memory/limit", 
  "network/rx", 
  "memory/major_page_faults_rate", 
  "uptime", 
  "memory/rss", 
  "memory/working_set", 
  "restart_count", 
  "network/tx_errors", 
  "cpu/request", 
  "cpu/limit", 
  "network/tx", 
  "memory/usage", 
  "network/tx_rate" 
 ]
```

In this example, there is no filesystem/usage in the list.

If I try to get it, I'll get exactly the same result to the one you’ve posted in the question:

http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy/api/v1/model/namespaces/kube-system/pods/etcd-minikube/metrics/filesystem/usage

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy/api/v1/model/namespaces/kube-system/pods/etcd-minikube/metrics/filesystem/usage 

{ 
  "metrics": [], 
  "latestTimestamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z" 
 }
```

Therefore, check the available options for the pod using URL similar to the first example.